# How to include jquery validate in a template

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am attempting to load jquery's validate methods in my template file.

The idea is to be able to run something like this:

```
$jquery("#generateForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    },
    rules: {
                ...
        }
    },
     messages: {
                  ...
        }
    }
});
```

Based on several posts, I've put this in my header.php file:

```
<?php

    function add_my_js_files(){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate-min', 
                          get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.validate.min.js', 
                          array( 'jquery' )  ) );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_js_files");
```

I have also tried to just link the file:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.validate.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

In *both* cases the error I get is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

In the jquery.validate.min.js file.

This appears to be because of the noConflict param that wordpress uses while loading jquery, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get around it.

How do i load this validate file?

Comment: How/Where are you adding the validate code?

Comment: @czerspalace the validation code is in the template file

Comment: What if you move the `add_my_js_files` and the `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_js_files')` into your functions.php?

Comment: put the code in `functions.php` as I've mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You're right. It's because of the jQuery noConflict mode.

You need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Or you can wrap everything in a function like this to define it's scope

```
(function($){
    $("#generateForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit();
        },
        rules: {
                ...
            }
        },
        messages: {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

> Based on several posts, I've put this in my header.php file:

Not in `header.php`. Put this code in your `functions.php` file.

```
function add_my_js_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate-min', 
                      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.validate.min.js', 
                      array( 'jquery' ) 
                     );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_js_files");
```

(There was an extra parentheses. I've removed that)

Comment: Are you parenthesis off?

Comment: Yes, they are.  You need an opening paren in front of `function`

Comment: This still doesnt work however.  I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.  Referring to the `.validate` method.

Comment: Putting that code in my functions.php file stopped my site from loading completely.

Comment: @paqogomez See my edit.

Comment: That did it.  The `function add_my_js_files()` function in my functions.php file allows me to add my javascript (`(function($)...` to my template file.