# Calling JavaScript file with Custom Plugin

Tags: plugins, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, validation

So, the goal is to use jQuery Validation for a custom form. Maybe I'm going about this the hard way. But, here's what I'm doing:

1. Uploaded the jQuery Validation file to my theme folder
2. Created plug-in folder in plug-in's file
3. Added php file with this code:

   ```
   function custom_validation() {

   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

   wp_register_script( 'jq-validation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.validation/jquery.validation.js', array('jquery'),'1',false );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jq-validation' );

   }

   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_validation' );
   ```

And, it's not working. I'm trying to avoid adding:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

To the header file. But, it works whenever I do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Where did you add the above code?

Comment: Getting this error:

chrismisterek.website/:592 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Added maybe an hour ago

Comment: Is that error from custom script you have added ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP loads jQuery in no conflict mode so shortcut **$** is not available for jQuery to use .You should not use the **$** variable for `jQuery` within WordPress.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   //code here
})
```

or

```
(function($){

    //code here

})(jQuery);
```

There are so many Q&A which refers to the same conflict issue.Check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189636/how-to-include-jquery-validate-in-a-template) and  [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=jquery%20conflict).

Comment: Thanks didn't realize my issue was in the script itself